# How to substract a polygon with GLUtesselator?

Tags: c++, windows, opengl, glu

I'm trying to make union from the polygons in this way:

[image]

You can see the direction from arrows: clockwise for holes and counterclockwise for solids.

But as the result shows, it doesn't work. I tried with all GLU_TESS_WINDING_RULE combinations but couldn't make it work.

Is this possible with bare GLUtesselator, or do I need some other library for this? Can Clipper lib do it?

Answer (score 0):

The [General Polygon Clipper library](http://www.cs.man.ac.uk/~toby/gpc/) can do boolean operations on polygons.

Comment: Does Clipper Lib also do that? (i heard it was better).

Comment: Had not heard of it.  Looks useful.

Comment: Yes. But the reason im trying to avoid it is because it requires the coordinate data to be in int64 format... so i need to convert back and forth, and im afraid of lost precision or calculation errors with huge numbers when i need at least 6dec and 3int precision.

Comment: looks like everything works good now. i multiply my floats with 10 million, to ensure 6 digit precision (+1 extra digit to reduce rounding errors when converting back to floats again, i think its enough?). im not sure how large number i can use to multiply the floats and keep calculations with int64 correct... i tried very large numbers and it seems to work anyways, but if i use those other features of this library, i think it will break eventually. i looked at the lib sources, and it looks like its using int128 for calculations, so, i think its bullet-proof?

Comment: Looks like i chose the wrong number o_O, for some reason with 10 million multiplication, it sometimes doesnt draw some triangles... (a LOT of them: 1/4) really weird. im just praying it works now as i expect :/ (with 1 million multiplication). i also tried with 16777216 but same effect came... 1000000000 seems to work too. does this make any sense to you?